# Multiple search parameters in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form that allows for several different search option inputs. Such as text boxs and drop downs. As of now I search by waiting for a search REQUEST and then seeing if there is any character input in the various text boxes or what drop down option is selected.

Basically it is branches of conditional logic using if statements then modifying the sql statement depending what is chosen. How can I make it to where it supports single options or several linked together?

Example of current condititional logic

```
$sql = "SELECT ";
if(strlen($_REQUEST['Option1']) > 0) {
            $sql .= "* FROM Table Where Option1 = {$_REQUEST['Option1']} ";
            }
        if(strlen($_REQUEST['Option 2']) > 0) {
            $sql .= "* From Table Where Option2 >= {$_REQUEST['Option2']}";
```

I understand I need to use AND in the sql query. I tried to do it with arrays of options then looping through depending on the boolean state but it didn't work

Comment: Also, you need to sanitize the sql variables. Use prepared SQL statements

Comment: Never ever ever insert a variable directly into a SQL statement. You set yourself up for SQL Injection attacks. Use PDO and their prepared statements to avoid this http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Put the where clauses in an array then do an implode with OR or AND:

`$sql .= implode(" AND ", $whereArray);`

Comment: you've updated my edit but in the meantime I already updated it.. now it is overwritten. is there no check for this in SO (eg: the document was modified in the meantime, are you sure?)?